# Can I put a work box next to a recessed light fixture that you would access by removing the fixture

Tags: electrical

I have a 3 wire coming from a 3 way switch behind a plaster wall ( *which I don't want to touch* ) going to new LED fixtures.

The box on the fixtures is limited to 4 12 gauge wires, So 2 in 2 out. In order to make the 3 way work, I need to make a connection in the ceiling, not in the fixture box.

Since the box for the LED is remote, and accessed by removing the light, could I just put a second work box next to it for the extra fill?

Again accessing both boxes by removing the light fixture.

I live in MD and under NEC 2017
Picture of remote LED added for clarity
[image]

Comment: Most fixtures are attached to a box, removing the fixture from the box does not give you access to the space behind or around the box. A can for a recessed light is usually fixed in place.  Clarification is needed.

Comment: @AlaskaMan -- most LED recessed "un-cans", including the OP's, use a cable-connected remote driver/JB that is accessed by removing the emitter/trim assembly from the ceiling finish.  (While one could have the driver/JB assembly mounted to the back of the emitter housing, it would be a real faff to deal with if the wiring to the fixture had to be hardpiped.)

Comment: @alaska man   I would agree but can lights usually have a small box built in , or many of the ones I have used. If there is a box that would be great for the OP

Comment: Why aren't you utilizing the box that's integral to the old can light, that presumably exists and already has wires gong to it? - Picture of what's up in the ceiling? Alternately, a light that doesn't have a remote and use smart switches. - code or not, I'd violate a fill before I made a mystery situation, just don't wire any 20a outlets onto the leg of the 3-way....

Comment: New construction in the kitchen. Utilizing one old switch box that already has 3 wire coming out (was 1 hot 1 neutral 1 switched hot) converting to 3 way switch and 7 "un cans" one which is pictured above. If I use the previous box (single octagon in the center) I would still have a rogue cover plate in my ceiling).  All that is up in the ceiling is MC 3wire hagning out in space. The smart switch still requires power which  would have to come from the original switch, which reduces the total number of wires, but does not reduce it enough.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  Had i known what kind of light he was using i would have understood that. It was not made clear before the photo was added. There are several kinds of LED  recessed  lights. I was assuming his reference to a "Box" was an electrical box.

Comment: Ah I get it: there *are no* existing can lights, and these new ones are plaster mount. Use a dome light (or w/e) on the singularly existing octagon or live with a plate (or run new MC, or buy one more light). If there are knockouts on the top of those new 'boxes', use a back-to-back connector (ideally it's on the top or you'll have trouble pulling the assembly in/out of the ceiling). - I'd have to find the code about 'accessibility' but iirc it's not all that well defined.

Comment: @Mazura - that 'box' has 4 knockouts. One roughly where the OP's thumb is in the pic, another on the opposite side, and 2 on the back end (the end opposite to the CCT switch and wire to the LEDs). So unfortunately non of them particularly useful for mounting an additional box.

Comment: @brhans - I could use a back to back to attach a box on the "top" of the drivers box. Physically it will work. Just not sure of the legality.